# "Star out" a grid function when given a NxM grid, returns grid with cells in a column or row originally containing a star turned into stars

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, grid

Been learning and doing Python the past few months but was given this JavaScript problem that I have been stuck on for hours and can't for the life of me figure out.

If we have a grid like this:

```
A B C
D * E
F G H
```

We should take every row and every column that contains a star (*) and star-out that row and column. So that grid would turn into:

```
A * C
* * *
F * H
```

A grid will be defined as an array-containing-arrays, so that original grid would be represented like this:

```
[ ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', '*', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H'] ]
```

Write a function that, given a NxM grid, like the one above, returns a grid with all cells in a column or row originally containing a star turned into stars. Values which have been transformed into stars do not affect their rows and columns. You should do this in-place – by changing the original grid, not by creating a new one. Your function should return the grid.

For example, for the input above, it should return:

```
[ ['A', '*', 'C'], ['*', '*', '*'], ['F', '*', 'H'] ]
```

This is the JS I have so far

```
function starOutGrid(grid) {
    for (let x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        const rowArray = grid[x]
        // console.log(rowArray)
        for (let y = 0; y < rowArray.length; y++) {
            const colArray = grid.map(c => c[y])
            if (colArray[y].includes("*")) {
                return colArray.replace(/[A-z]/g, "*")
            }
            console.log(colArray)
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if using includes and replace are the way to go or to try to push and pull? Pretty rusty with doing JS problems like this so the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the problem that we have to watch out for is this:

> Values which have been transformed into stars do not affect their rows and columns.

Since we are modifying the grid in-place, we have to be sure we no longer need a value for evaluation purposes before changing it. We can modify each row as it is spent, tracking the column states separately. Then we can go back and modify the columns.

Here is my approach:

```js
const starOutGrid = grid => {
  const width = grid[0].length;
  const columns = Array(width).fill(false);

  grid.forEach(row => {
    row.forEach((column, i) => {
      if (column === '*') {
        columns[i] = true;
      }
    });

    if (row.includes('*')) {
      for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        row[i] = '*';
      }
    }
  });

  columns.forEach((column, i) => {
    if (column) {
      grid.forEach(row => {
        row[i] = '*';
      });
    }
  });

  return grid;
};
```